# How to access mongo db collection "records"? db_connect.collection is not a function error | MERN APP

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-router

I have the following code in a file called record.js which defines routes for an express api and is contained by server.js along with app.listen(), the server listener.

```
const express = require(“express”);
const recordRoutes = express.Router();
const dbo = require(“../db/conn”);

recordRoutes.route(“/record”).get(function (req, res) { 
    let db_connect = dbo.getDb('mernit');
    console.log(db_connect);
    db_connect
        .collection(“records”)
        .find({})
        .toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(result);
        });
    res.send(“hello_world");
});
```

This code is written according to: https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial
but with a simplified server side.

I receive the following error after ensuring server connection, console logging the db_connect object, and attempting to access the collection, "records".

```
TypeError: db_connect.collection is not a function
    at C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\routes\record.js:20:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\bbell\projects\MERN\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

error throws on '.collection(“records”)'...

Additionally, the Front End returns HTTP response code 500 when attempting to GET on http://localhost:3000/record.

I am using Mongo 4.4.10 with Atlas. I looked into the problem a bit and it seems the connection method may have been deprecated or reworked in some earlier version.

However, the tutorial (linked above), if up to date, would suggest the function is still valid.

Does anyone know why my route is failing to access, and how to successfully access, my database collection 'records'?

Thanks,

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "employees" the code for this route should look like this

```
recordRoutes.route("/record").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  db_connect
    .collection("records")
    .find({})
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
});
```

Also your  `res.send("hello world)` line is missing the closing quote.

Comment: had been experimenting with the db name there and not there. same error happens when I include it.

Comment: also hello world quotes have since been fixed but were not the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

Got it after reverting some changes to the conn.js file and deleting some stray res.funcs .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I was able to follow this part of the tutorial and did not get an error.